# How to query if record exists for prior month in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with custId and orderDate fields, and I need a query to display whether or not the custId in that record has another record in the table with an order from the prior month. For example:

```
custId   orderDate    hasOrderInPriorMonth
aaa      2017-11-01   false
bbb      2017-12-15   false
aaa      2018-01-29   false
bbb      2018-01-15   true
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use variables to calculate the flag. The variables will store the values of `custId` and `orderDate` as well as the calculated flag value. All three will be used to calculate the subsequent row's flag.

You will need to sort the rows by `custId`, then by `orderDate` and implement the following logic to calculate the flag values:

- if the current row's `custId` is different from the one stored in the corresponding variable (which at this point is carrying the previous `custId`), set the flag to false;
- otherwise, if the year and month of the current row's `orderDate` match those of the date stored in the corresponding variable (which, similarly, is the date from the previous row), keep the previous flag value;
- otherwise, set the flag to true if the current `orderId` minus one month is the same year and month as the date stored in the variable;
- store the current `custId` and the year and month of the current `orderId` for use in the next iteration.

The MySQL-specific SQL query for that could be something like this:

```
SELECT
  custId,
  orderDate,
  flag AS hasOrderInPriorMonth
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      @flag :=
        CASE
          WHEN o.custId <> @custId THEN false
          WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM o.orderDate) = @orderMonth THEN @flag
          ELSE (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM o.orderDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = @orderMonth)
        END AS flag,
      @custId := o.custId as custId,
      o.orderDate,
      @orderMonth := EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM o.orderDate)
    FROM
      (SELECT @custId := '', @orderMonth := 0, @flag := false) as x,
      orders as o
    ORDER BY
      custId    ASC,
      orderDate ASC
  ) AS s
;
```

A demo of this query is available [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/981608/10). (It borrows the test setup created by [Jehad Keriaki](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/29289/jehad-keriaki) for [his own answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/197330/6965).)

Answer (score 2):

[TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function is useful here:

```
[mysql] desc orders;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| custId    | char(10) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| orderDate | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

[mysql] select * from orders;
+--------+------------+
| custId | orderDate  |
+--------+------------+
| aaa    | 2017-11-01 |
| bbb    | 2017-12-15 |
| aaa    | 2018-01-29 |
| bbb    | 2018-01-15 |
+--------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

[mysql] select 
    o.custId, 
    o.orderDate, 
    IF((select count(*) from orders o2 
        where o.custId=o2.custId and 
        timestampdiff(MONTH, o2.orderDate, o.orderDate)=1) >= 1, 
        "TRUE", "FALES") 
    as hasOrderInPriorMonth 
from orders o;
+--------+------------+----------------------+
| custId | orderDate  | hasOrderInPriorMonth |
+--------+------------+----------------------+
| aaa    | 2017-11-01 | FALES                |
| bbb    | 2017-12-15 | FALES                |
| aaa    | 2018-01-29 | FALES                |
| bbb    | 2018-01-15 | TRUE                 |
+--------+------------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/981608/1

Comment: Why `(select count(*) from ...) = 1` rather than `exists (select * from ...)`? I'm asking that generally but there's also a more specific concern: what if a customer can have more than one order per month? Relying on `count(*) = 1` could then give you incorrect results.

Comment: Right @AndriyM I changed it to ">="

Comment: This gives you the first of last month:  `CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Answer (score 0):

Join this table back to itself:

```
SELECT ordersA.custId,
ordersA.orderDate AS thisOrderDate,
COUNT(ordersB.orderDate) AS priorMonthOrders
FROM orders AS ordersA LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS ordersB
ON ordersA.custId = ordersB.custId
AND ordersB.orderDate >= date_sub(ordersA.orderDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND ordersB.orderDate < ordersA.orderDate
GROUP BY ordersA.custId, ordersA.orderDate;
```

Comment: I think if there is more than one order to the same client in the previous month, this query will give you duplicates

Comment: Great point, Jehad. I added a GROUP BY and just return a count now to avoid that issue. (Also was missing the custId match in the join, but that was probably obvious.) Thanks!

Comment: In fact, there is another problem. It could be that the difference is 35 days, yet it is in the previous month. This query will ignore this case.

Comment: I suppose that's true, though if that's a problem probably depends on what CraigV meant by "an order from the prior month". I could see several interpretations of that phrase.  If it is a problem, wrap those with MONTH() to reduce them to the first of the respective months and essentially flatten the day-in-month aspect of the fields.

Comment: This is useful to test the queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/981608/2